# Keyboard stopped working on Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard

Yesterday the keyboard from my notebook was working nice, but I woke up today and it was not working on Win10, Ubuntu, nor Windows DVD. It works in the BIOS, but a weird thing happens (I will explain later), and in the Ubuntu LiveCD too.

When I enter into the setup, my keystrokes are delayed by 3 keystrokes. What I mean is, if I press DOWN, DOWN, LEFT, UP, UP, UP, in the first 3 presses, nothing happens, then it starts to do all the previous actions instead of doing the newest one. On the example sequence, when I press UP, it goes DOWN, then I press UP again (or any other, just using the example above), it executes the second DOWN, then I press UP again and it goes LEFT after I press something (random, out of the example sequence), then it goes on the UP, UP, UP, just like a FIFO line, but I have to put 3 elements before start running the line. If anyone doesn't understood what happened here, just comment and I will try to explain better.

I have changed OS, deleted partitions, everything to ensure that it isn't an OS issue.

What I HAVE NOT DONE yet is reset or update the BIOS. I have followed several tutorials of problems that looks like mine, but not exactly.

Someone have a clue? If I reset the BIOS, is there any chance of this solving the problem?

I have a Samsung X20 with 8GB Ram, I7, NVIDIA 780M.

Thank you. I appreciate your help. (If you can't understand, tell me and I will write it another way. I don't have English as my native language.)

Answer (score 0):

You've been using an external keyboard to change the OS and delete partitions, etc? And that works fine?

If an external keyboard works fine, but the internal one does not, then change the internal keyboard.

Try running a full anti-virus scan. And anti-malware.

Comment: No, i was using the internal one, has i said, it works on the liveCD but not in the system. No virus or malwares, i've changed the hd..

Comment: So, you didn't *change* the OS, you just booted from a different OS.

What partitions did you delete? And why?

I wouldn't worry about OSes since this is happening in the BIOS.

Find/buy yourself an external, wired keyboard and see if that's any better.

Also, if your laptop's keyboard is easy to remove, try removing it, doing any obvious cleaning, and reseating the connection. That might help, too.

Was there any damage (liquid, dust, humidity?) to the keyboard?

Comment: I've changed, i was using windows 10, then this happened, i wipped the HD and installed Ubuntu it didn't worked, then i wipped it again and came back to Windows, on windows it wasn't working, but after i close the lid, the computer went into sleep mode, when i woke up it, the keyboard was working, after a restart, it stopped again, i did the sleep thing again and it was back normal again.. That's strange.. It is working fine now and i don't have a clue about what happened..